# trouble with yahtzee in java

Tags: java, methods, return

I have to create the yahtzee game and its methods like full house, small straight, big straight, 3 of kind, 4 of kind , and chance. Now this is what i have done so far and i would like to know if my methods are right and also i'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to check if its yahtzee , 3 of kind, 4 of kind , etc and this is in my main method. The program consists of seven rolls, where every roll can have up to two sub-rolls

```
 static final int NUM_RERROLS_ = 2;
    static final int NUM_OF_DICE = 5;

    static final int NUM_ROLLS_ = 7;
    static final int[] dice = new int[NUM_OF_DICE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        rollDice();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RERROLS_; i++) {

            if (gotYatzee()) {

                break;
            }

            System.out.println(diceToString());
            askUser();

            System.out.println("Which dice do you want to reroll: ");
            secondReroll(convert(keyboard.nextLine()));

        }
        System.out.println(diceToString());
        if (gotYatzee()) {
            System.out.println("You got Yatzee & 50 points!");

        } else if (largeStraight() == true) {
            System.out.println("You got large straight");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry no large straight");
        }

        if (smallStraight() == true) {
            System.out.println("You got smallStraight");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry no small straight");
        }
        if (fullHouse() == true) {
            System.out.println("You got full house");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry no full house");
        }

        {
            System.out.println("SORRY NO YAHTZEE");

        }
        if (askUser() == false) {
            if (largeStraight() == true) {
                System.out.println("You got large straight");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry no large straight");
            }

            if (smallStraight() == true) {
                System.out.println("You got smallStraight");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry no small straight");
            }
            if (fullHouse() == true) {
                System.out.println("You got full house");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry no full house");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void rollDice() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DICE; i++) {
            dice[i] = randomValue();
        }
    }

    public static int randomValue() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    public static String diceToString() {
        String dado = "Here are your dice: ";
        for (int element : dice) {
            dado = dado + element + " ";
        }
        return dado;
    }

    public static boolean gotYatzee() {
        for (int element : dice) {
            if (element != dice[0]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void secondReroll(int[] newValue) {
        for (int element : newValue) {
            dice[element - 1] = randomValue();
        }
    }

    public static int[] convert(String s) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
        int[] a = new int[st.countTokens()];
        int i = 0;

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            a[i++] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static boolean Chance() {
        for (int element : dice) {
            int i = 0;
            if (element != dice[i]) {
                i++;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean smallStraight() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_DICE; i++) {
            boolean b = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_DICE; j++) {
                b = b || (dice[j] == i);
            }
            if (!b) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean largeStraight() {
        int[] i = new int[5];
        i = dice;
        sortArray(i);

        if (((i[0] == 1) && (i[1] == 2) && (i[2] == 3) && (i[3] == 4) && (i[4] == 5))
                || ((i[0] == 2) && (i[1] == 3) && (i[2] == 4) && (i[3] == 5) && (i[4] == 6))
                || ((i[1] == 1) && (i[2] == 2) && (i[3] == 3) && (i[4] == 4) && (i[5] == 5))
                || ((i[1] == 2) && (i[2] == 3) && (i[3] == 4) && (i[4] == 5) && (i[5] == 6))) {
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }

    public static boolean askUser() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        String yes = "Yes";
        String no = "No";
        System.out.println("Do you want to reroll the dice again:  Yes or No? ");
        String userInput;
        userInput = keyboard.next();
        if (userInput.equals(yes)) {
            System.out.println("ALRIGHTY!!");
            return true;

        } else if (userInput.equals(no)) {

        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean threeKind() {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a = dice;
        sortArray(a);
        if ((((a[0] == a[1]) && (a[1] == a[2])) // Three of a Kind
                || ((a[1] == a[2]) && ((a[2] == a[3])
                || (((a[2] == a[3]) && (a[3] == a[4]))))))) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*public static boolean fourKind(int[] dice) {




     }
     */
    public static int[] sortArray(int[] numbers) {

        int stop;
        for (stop = 0; stop < numbers.length; stop++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {

                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
                    swap(numbers, i, i + 1);
                }

            }

        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] numbers, int pos1, int pos2) {
        int temp = numbers[pos1];
        numbers[pos1] = numbers[pos2];
        numbers[pos2] = temp;

    }

    public static boolean fullHouse() {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a = dice;
        sortArray(a);

        if ((((a[0] == a[1]) && (a[1] == a[2])) && // Three of a Kind
                (a[3] == a[4]) && // Two of a Kind
                (a[2] != a[3]))
                || ((a[0] == a[1]) && // Two of a Kind
                ((a[2] == a[3]) && (a[3] == a[4])) && // Three of a Kind
                (a[1] != a[2]))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code given? What were the errors. Stacktrace?

Comment: basically i want to figure out a way to check if its full  house, 3 of kind, 4 of kind , etc .

Comment: Where in the code IS the issue?

Comment: If you want a generic code review / suggstions, post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> basically i want to figure out a way to check if its full house, 3 of kind, 4 of kind , etc

You have 6 dice after three rolls. Sort the array of user-retained dice after the 3 rolls.

Yahtzee:  `((die[0] == die[4]) || (die[1] == die[5]))`
4 of a kind: `((die[0] == die[3]) || (die[1] == die[4] || (die[2] == die[5]))`
Small straight, 3 tests (x = 3,4,5): `((die[x] - die[x-3]) == 3)`
Large straight, 2 tests (x = 4,5): `((die[x] - die[x-4]) == 4)`
etc.

Chance: Up to the user, right?

Unless I'm missing something (I'm a little rusty on Yatzee), this should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: NP.  Actually, there are a few cases that do add a minor twist - for example, Yahtzee can also be 4 of a kind, 3 of a kind or a full house (which could itself also be 3 of a kind).  If you're developing something for humans, choice will be important.  Also, although I doubt this is a performance-critical problem, the order in which you test the results can make a difference - for example no three of a kind implicitly means no full house.  The old adage "Make it readable, make it run, then make it run fast if you have to" would seem to apply here.